# Social network with video chat feature using neo4j

Tags: database, graph, database-design, neo4j, graph-databases

I am using neo4j to build a social network web app where users that are friends can communicate with each other through video calls. Each participating user will also be able to submit a review at the end of each call. I structured the graph such that two `(:User)` nodes can have a `[:FRIEND]` relationship between each other. For a particular video call, I am planning on creating a `(:VideoCall)` node (which contains properties such as roomId) and a `[:PARTICIPANT]` relationship from the `(:VideoCall)` node to each participating `(:User)` node. The `[:PARTICIPANT]` relationship will have a `rating` property containing the user's review for that video call. Would this model be performant if there are a large number of user and video call nodes? Is there a better way to design the database for this type of feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it should be performing well. Just make sure you have properties that you want to look up by indexed and constraints in place

What kind of use cases would you want to cover besides regular ones?

Comment: Currently, I have set up a unique constraint for the userID property within the User label and a unique constraint on the roomId property within the VideoCall label for quick lookup. Would it make sense to index the dateCreated property on the VideoCall label if I want to query a subset of the video calls between 2 users based on date? I also want to store notifications sent to each user (for example, when they receive a friend request). Another use case in the future may be to add text message functionality between 2 users. A graph database may not be the best choice for that feature. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is a good model if the video calls involve multiple users AND you want to use roomId as a condition for queries because in this way you can easily find all users that have participated in a specific video call.

However, I noticed that you mentioned it is a social networking web app. So chances are the video calls are just between TWO users. If that's the case, then there'a an alternative to your current model: Make video calls as an edge between users:  `(:user)-[:videocall]->(:user)` Properties such as roomId can be assigned to the edge. This model saves memory because you have fewer nodes.